# getting 'ORA-00922: missing or invalid option' error when I'm trying to run the below plsql code. how to solve it?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
 var_test1 VARCHAR2(30) := 'RebellionRider';
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (var_test1);
END;
```

---

Whenever im running the above code im getting the following error. Im using oracle apex to run my code. how to solve it?
Error:-

> ORA-00922: missing or invalid option

```
BEGIN
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (var_test1);
END;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you use Apex, where *exactly* did you run that code? It works just fine in its **SQL Workshop** (SQL Commands).

Just remove `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON`, it is SQL*Plus command to enable the output, it is

- meaningless in Apex
- raises ORA-00922 (in Apex)

Comment: Thank you. Removing SET SERVEROUTPUT ON  worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

When you are on developer environment, you can to select only the text you want run, so press F5 or click run. This will also working.

Comment: This isn't particularly helpful. Which text do you think the OP should select and run?